# Javascript, same function, multiple elements one at a time

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I created a carousel slider similar to the one in UIkit slider, I want to use this function to multiple carousel in the same html page but it's not working as expected because I am using this line of code which query single carousel only:

```
const carousel = document.querySelector(".c-carousel-inner");
```

I've tried using this but apparently on button press it will trigger the other carousel also

```
const carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".c-carousel-inner");
carousels.forEach((carousel) => {
// code here
});
```

I've seen some solution which uses constructor, but I'm not sure if that's the best approach here

Here's my **full javascript** code without any applied code from above

```
const carousel = document.querySelector(".c-carousel-inner");
const carouselLength = carousel.children.length;
const carouselItemWidth = document.querySelector(".c-carousel-inner .c-carousel-item").offsetWidth;
const carouselButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".c-carousel-control");
let startX, scrollSum = 0, mouseIsDown, count = 0, mx, moving=false, lastDirection, prevScroll;

carouselButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if (button.id == "carousel-right") {
            if (prevScroll) {
                mouseToLeft();
            }
            prevScroll = true;
            moveToLeftSnap();

        } else if (button.id == "carousel-left") {
            if (!prevScroll) {
                mouseToRight();
            }
            moveToRightSnap();
            prevScroll = false;
        }
    });
})

function mouseToLeft() {
    if (count >= carouselLength) {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    for (i=0; i < carouselLength; i++) {
        carousel.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
        if (i < count) {
            carousel.children[i].style.order = "1";
        }
    }
}

function mouseToRight() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        count = carouselLength;
    }
    count--;    
    for (i=carouselLength-1; i>=0; i--) {
        carousel.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
        if (i >= count) {
            carousel.children[i].style.order = "-1";
        }        
    }
}

function moveToRightSnap(value=carouselItemWidth) {
    carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
    carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(-${value}px, 0, 0)`;
    setTimeout(() => {
        carousel.style.transition = `transform 0.342s ease`;
        carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0, 0)`;
    }, 1); 
}

function moveToLeftSnap(value=0) {
    carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
    carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${value}, 0, 0)`;
    setTimeout(() => {
        carousel.style.transition = `transform 0.342s ease`;
        carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(-${carouselItemWidth}px, 0, 0)`;
    }, 1);
}

const startDrag = (e) => {
    mouseIsDown = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    mx = e.pageX;
    carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
}

const dragging = (e) => {
    if (mouseIsDown) {
        scrollSum = e.pageX - startX;
        console.log(scrollSum);
        if (mx < e.pageX) {
            lastDirection = "right";
        } else if (mx > e.pageX) {
            lastDirection = "left"
        }
        if (scrollSum > 0) {
            startX = e.pageX + carouselItemWidth;
            scrollSum = scrollSum - carouselItemWidth;
            if (!prevScroll) {
                mouseToRight();
            }
        } else if (prevScroll || scrollSum <= -carouselItemWidth) {
            scrollSum = 0;
            startX = e.pageX;
            mouseToLeft();
            prevScroll = false;
        }
        carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${scrollSum}px,0,0)`;
        mx = e.pageX;
    }
} 

const stopDrag = () => {
    mouseIsDown = false;
    if (lastDirection == "right") {
        moveToRightSnap(scrollSum);
    } else if (lastDirection == "left") {
        moveToLeftSnap(scrollSum);
        prevScroll = true;
    }
}

carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);

document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);

document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag);
```

**HTML code** currently only single carousel is added here to make it short

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="c-carousel">
      <ul id="" class="c-carousel-inner d-flex">
        <% topAiring.forEach((item, index) => { %>
        <li class="c-carousel-item item-<%= index + 1 %> col-3 <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
          <img src="<%= item.images.jpg['image_url'] %>" draggable="false" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </li>
        <% }) %>
      </ul>
      <button id="carousel-left" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button id="carousel-right" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you need to know what button is linked to what carousel. The code overuses globals so you need to refactor it so variables are not global and are related to the instance.

Comment: @epascarello Hi, have updated my answer, let me know if you have any comment for me to improve better, thank youu!

Answer (score 1):

This code as it is has some fundamental issues. Most noticeably, in the case of multiple carousels you will get duplicated `id`s. `id` should be a unique identifier for any element.

**(Please see the event bubbling solution below as my recommended approach)**

### 1 - Building upon your existing approach:

Instead of `id`, you can use `data` attribute on your buttons. For example:

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="c-carousel">
      <ul id="carousel_01" class="c-carousel-inner d-flex">
        <% topAiring.forEach((item, index) => { %>
        <li class="c-carousel-item item-<%= index + 1 %> col-3 <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
          <img src="<%= item.images.jpg['image_url'] %>" draggable="false" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </li>
        <% }) %>
      </ul>
      <button id="l_01" data-direction="left" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button id="r_01" data-direction="right" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your function will then become something like:

```js
carouselButtons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        const btnIdTail = button.id.split("_")[1];
        const carousel = document.getElementById(`carousel_${btnIdTail}`);
        const btnDir = button.dataset.direction;
        if (btnDir == "right") {
            if (prevScroll) {
                mouseToLeft(carousel);
            }
            prevScroll = true;
            moveToLeftSnap(carousel);

        } else if (btnDir == "left") {
            if (!prevScroll) {
                mouseToRight(carousel);
            }
            moveToRightSnap(carousel);
            prevScroll = false;
        }
    });
})
```

Get the carousel by their `id` based on the button `id`. In your handler functions use the specific carousel which you pass in, like:

```js
function mouseToLeft(carousel) {
    const carouselLength = carousel.children.length;
    if (count >= carouselLength) {
        count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    for (i=0; i < carouselLength; i++) {
        carousel.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
        if (i < count) {
            carousel.children[i].style.order = "1";
        }
    }
}
function moveToRightSnap(carousel, value=carouselItemWidth) {
    //...
}

function moveToLeftSnap(carousel, value=0) {
    //...
}
```

and do the same for other functions.
Don't forget to `id` your carousels with the same kind of numbering you used for its `button` like:

```html
<ul id="carousel_01" class="c-carousel-inner d-flex">
```

To implement dragging handles, get the target carousel from the event and pass it on to the functions as above. Like:

```js
const startDrag = (e) => {
    // get the carousel
    const carousel = e.target;
    mouseIsDown = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    mx = e.pageX;
    carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
}

const dragging = (e) => {
    // get the carousel, use and pass it
    const carousel = e.target;
    const carouselItemWidth = carousel.offsetWidth;
    if (mouseIsDown) {
        scrollSum = e.pageX - startX;
        console.log(scrollSum);
        if (mx < e.pageX) {
            lastDirection = "right";
        } else if (mx > e.pageX) {
            lastDirection = "left"
        }
        if (scrollSum > 0) {
            startX = e.pageX + carouselItemWidth;
            scrollSum = scrollSum - carouselItemWidth;
            if (!prevScroll) {
                mouseToRight(carousel);
            }
        } else if (prevScroll || scrollSum <= -carouselItemWidth) {
            scrollSum = 0;
            startX = e.pageX;
            mouseToLeft(carousel);
            prevScroll = false;
        }
        carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${scrollSum}px,0,0)`;
        mx = e.pageX;
    }
} 

const stopDrag = (e) => {
    const carousel = e.target;
    mouseIsDown = false;
    if (lastDirection == "right") {
        moveToRightSnap(carousel, scrollSum);
    } else if (lastDirection == "left") {
        moveToLeftSnap(carousel, scrollSum);
        prevScroll = true;
    }
}
```

You will need to localise `scrollSum` and other variables that can impact other carousels. I will leave that to you

### 2 - Solution with event bubbling:

Alternatively, you can make use of event bubbling that will reduce the number of listeners and negates the need for `id`s.  Here is one way to achieve that:

```js
const carCtrl = {
  mouseState: "",
  index: 0,
  car: null,
  width: 0,
  len: 0,
  dir: "",
  isMoving: false,
  startX: [],
  mX: [],
  scrollSum: [],
  count: [],
  previous: [],
  lastDir: [],

  setArrays: (qty) => {
    const fill = (v) => new Array(qty).fill(v);
    this.count = fill(0);
    this.startX = fill(0);
    this.mX = fill(0);
    this.scrollSum = fill(0);
    this.previous = fill(false);
    this.lastDir = fill("");
  },
  set: (e, index) => {
    this.car = e.target;
    // check if the click event has button with direction data
    // if not it returns false for early return to terminate the even
    if (Object.hasOwn(this.car.dataSet, "direction"))
      this.dir = this.car.dataSet.direction;
    else return false;
    this.width = this.getWidth(e.target);
    this.len = e.target.children.length;
    this.index = index;
    return true;
  },

  getWidth: (el) => {
    if (!el) return 0;
    if (el?.children?.length) {
      return el.children[0].offsetWidth;
    }
    return el.offsetWidth;
  },

  trigger:(e, index)=>{
    if (!this.set(e)) return; // early return. not a click on a button

    const motion = this.dir=== "right" ? 
      {dir: "left", pre: true, val: 0} : 
      {dir: "right", pre: false, val: this.width};

    if (this.previous[index] === motion.pre) {
        this.move(motion.dir);
    }
    this.previous[index] = motion.pre;
    this.snap(motion.val, this.dir);
  },      

  move: (dir) => {
    const index = this.index;
    
    if (dir === "left") {
      // move left
      if (this.count[index] >= this.len) {
        this.count[index] = 0;
      }
      this.count[index]++;
      for (i = 0; i < this.len; i++) {
        this.car.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
        if (i < this.count[index]) {
          this.car.children[i].style.order = "1";
        }
      }
    } else {
      // move right
      if (this.count[index] <= 0) {
        this.count[index] = carouselLength;
      }
      this.count[index]--;
      for (i = this.len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        this.car.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
        if (i >= this.count[index]) {
          this.car.children[i].style.order = "-1";
        }
      }
    }
  },

  snap: (val, dir) => {
    const fromX = dir === "right" ? -val : val;
    const toX = (dir === "right") ? -this.width : 0;
    this.car.style.removeProperty("transition");
    this.car.style.transform = `translate3d(${fromX}px, 0, 0)`;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.car.style.transition = `transform 0.342s ease`;
      this.car.style.transform = `translate3d(${toX}px, 0, 0)`;
    }, 1);
  },

  startDrag: (e, i) => {
    this.mouseState = "down";
    this.startX[i] = e.pageX;
    this.mX[i] = e.pageX;
    e.target.style.removeProperty("transition");
  },

  dragging: (e, i) => {
    const width = e.target.offsetWidth;
    if (this.mouseState === "down") {
      this.scrollSum[i] = e.pageX - this.startX[i];
      console.log(this.scrollSum[i]);
      this.lastDir[i] = this.mX[i] < e.pageX ? "right" : "left";

      if (this.scrollSum[i] > 0) {
        this.startX[i] = e.pageX + width;
        this.scrollSum[i] = this.scrollSum[i] - width;
        if (!this.previous[i]) this.move("right");
      } else if (this.previous[i] || this.scrollSum[i] <= -width) {
        this.scrollSum[i] = 0;
        this.startX[i] = e.pageX;
        this.move("left");
        this.previous[i] = false;
      }
      carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${this.scrollSum[i]}px,0,0)`;
      this.mX[i] = e.pageX;
    }
  },

  stopDrag: (e, i) => {
    this.mouseState = "up";
    this.snap(this.scrollSum[i], this.lastDir[i]);
    this.previous[i] = this.lastDir[i] === "left" ? true : this.lastDir[i];
  },
};

window.addEventListener("load", caresouling);

function caresouling() {
  const carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".c-carousel-inner");

  carCtrl.setArrays(carousels.length);
  const events = [
    ["click", "trigger"],
    ["mousedown", "startDrag"],
    ["mousemove", "dragging"],
    ["mouseup", "stopDrag"],
  ];
  carousels.forEach((car, i) => {
    events.forEach(evnt => {
      car.addEventListener(evnt[0], (e, i) => carCtrl[evnt[1]](e, i));
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- First caresoul -->
    <div class="c-carousel">
      <ul class="c-carousel-inner d-flex">
        <% topAiring1.forEach((item, index) => { %>
          <li class="c-carousel-item item-<%= index + 1 %> col-3 <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
            <img src="<%= item.images.jpg['image_url'] %>" draggable="false" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </li>
          <% }) %>
      </ul>
      <button data-direction="left" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button data-direction="right" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- another caresoul -->
    <div class="c-carousel">
      <ul class="c-carousel-inner d-flex">
        <% topAiring2.forEach((item, index) => { %>
          <li class="c-carousel-item item-<%= index + 1 %> col-3 <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
            <img src="<%= item.images.jpg['image_url'] %>" draggable="false" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
          </li>
          <% }) %>
      </ul>
      <button data-direction="left" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button data-direction="right" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

**⚠️NOTE! The snippet won't work without carousels being correctly populated!**

(Please note that I did not consider the logic, so I cannot be sure if this logic works or is the best approach. My answer just is an attempt to give a working solution based on your existing logic.)

In this solution, you get the event listeners on the high level carousel, then we check to see if the use hit any of the directional buttons and trigger the move.
The object carCtrl keeps the reference to all the variables your code's logic needs to track. Because they're arrays in an object they are passes as reference and so will be shared between all carousels.

Comment: Hi Bruce, thanks for the enlightenment, you're right about the button ids, I just refactored my code. I tried yours but can't seem to find solution to "count" and other variables. I made it work now though, thanks again!

Comment: Hey @JustR. I updated the answer. Please see *Solution with event bubbling*. The carCtrl will keep track of your variables for each carousel and you won't need `id`s for it at all.
Please read the code and note the approach. I hope that helps you refining your code.

I saw the other answer that was partially copied mine. Not sure that constantly fiddling with the DOM is a good idea in general.

Answer (score 1):

If you know which carousel is clicked or draged, you can do it easily. right?

-javascript

```
let carousel = document.createElement('div');
const carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".c-carousel");
carousels.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("mousedown", () => {
    carousel = e.children[0];  //get .c-carousel-inner from .c-carousel
  });
});
//when you mouse down in any carousel (including button in it) this'll works and variable 'carousel' will be clicked carousel. ok?
 
...
...


carouselButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    //I change click to mouseup because handling mousedown event on carousel must be first and then handle button event.

    if (button.carousel-direction == "right") {
      if (prevScroll) {
        mouseToLeft();
      }
      prevScroll = true;
      moveToLeftSnap();
    } else if (button.carousel-direction == "left") {
      if (!prevScroll) {
        mouseToRight();
      }
      moveToRightSnap();
      prevScroll = false;
    }
  });
});

    
...
...
```

-html

```
  <button id="l_01" carousel-direction="left" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true">. 
    </span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button id="r_01" carousel-direction="right" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true">. 
    </span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
```

I hope this answer can help you.

Good luck.

Oh, don't forget to vote my answer if it works.

Comment: @Bruce, If you do like that, how about dragging?   if you drag carousel2 how dragging handlers know which carousel is dragged?

Comment: Hi @J.Porter, thank you for your help, I did some refactoring of my code and applied some of your approach and it's working now. You can check my own answer, I'm not confident yet if I followed coding standards so let me know if you have any critics. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone! Much appreciated. I am not confident about how I approach this one but let me know if there's anything I can improve!

**JS**

```
const carousels = document.querySelectorAll(".c-carousel");

carousels.forEach((element) => {
    const carousel = element.querySelector(".c-carousel-inner");
    const carouselLength = carousel.children.length;
    const carouselItemWidth = carousel.querySelector(".c-carousel-item").offsetWidth;
    const carouselButtons = element.querySelectorAll(".c-carousel-control");
    let startX, scrollSum = 0, mouseIsDown, count = 0, mx, lastDirection, prevScroll;

    carouselButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", function(){
            const btnDir = button.dataset.direction;
            if (btnDir == "right") {
                if (prevScroll) {
                    mouseToLeft();
                }
                prevScroll = true;
                moveToLeftSnap();
            } else if (btnDir == "left") {
                if (!prevScroll) {
                    mouseToRight();
                }
                prevScroll = false;
                moveToRightSnap();
            }
        });
    });

    function mouseToLeft() {
        if (count >= carouselLength) {
            count = 0;
        }
        count++;
        for (i=0; i < carouselLength; i++) {
            carousel.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
            if (i < count) {
                carousel.children[i].style.order = "1";
            }
        }
    }

    function mouseToRight() {
        if (count <= 0) {
            count = carouselLength;
        }
        count--;    
        for (i=carouselLength-1; i>=0; i--) {
            carousel.children[i].style.removeProperty("order");
            if (i >= count) {
                carousel.children[i].style.order = "-1";
            }        
        }
    }

    function moveToRightSnap(value=carouselItemWidth) {
        carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
        carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(-${value}px, 0, 0)`;
        setTimeout(() => {
            carousel.style.transition = `transform 0.342s ease`;
            carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(0, 0, 0)`;
        }, 1); 
    }

    function moveToLeftSnap(value=0) {
        carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
        carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${value}, 0, 0)`;
        setTimeout(() => {
            carousel.style.transition = `transform 0.342s ease`;
            carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(-${carouselItemWidth}px, 0, 0)`;
        }, 1);
    }

    const startDrag = (e) => {
        mouseIsDown = true;
        startX = e.pageX;
        mx = e.pageX;
        carousel.style.removeProperty("transition");
    }

    const dragging = (e) => {
        if (mouseIsDown) {
            scrollSum = e.pageX - startX;
            if (mx < e.pageX) {
                lastDirection = "right";
            } else if (mx > e.pageX) {
                lastDirection = "left"
            }
            if (scrollSum > 0) {
                startX = e.pageX + carouselItemWidth;
                scrollSum = scrollSum - carouselItemWidth;
                if (!prevScroll) {
                    mouseToRight();
                }
            } else if (prevScroll || scrollSum <= -carouselItemWidth) {
                scrollSum = 0;
                startX = e.pageX;
                mouseToLeft();
                prevScroll = false;
            }
            carousel.style.transform = `translate3d(${scrollSum}px,0,0)`;
            mx = e.pageX;
        }
    } 

    const stopDrag = () => {
        mouseIsDown = false;
        if (lastDirection == "right") {
            moveToRightSnap(scrollSum);
        } else if (lastDirection == "left") {
            moveToLeftSnap(scrollSum);
            prevScroll = true;
        }
        lastDirection="";
    }

    carousel.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragging);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", stopDrag);

});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="c-carousel">
      <ul id="" class="c-carousel-inner d-flex">
        <% topAiring.forEach((item, index) => { %>
        <li class="c-carousel-item item-<%= index + 1 %> col-3 <%= index == 0 ? 'active' : '' %>">
          <img src="<%= item.images.jpg['image_url'] %>" draggable="false" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </li>
        <% }) %>
      </ul>
      <button data-direction="left" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button data-direction="right" class="c-carousel-control" type="button">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want my advice
-Don’t use many global variables.
  You used so many global variables in javascript like carousel, carouslelLength, carouselItemWidth, carouselButtons in your previous code. It’s not good to manage lifecycle of your app.
-Reduce code as possible. In your code, there are many parts of unnecessary code.
 For example,
 mouseToRight and mouseToLeft is not so different.
 This also happens between moveToRightSnap and moveToLeftSnap.
 You can merge functions into one and handle different part with arguments.
I wish my advice can help you even a little.
Good luck!

Comment: I want you to accept my answer. ok?